# github page folder naming problem with trailing /

Tags: url, github, github-pages

[bhat.dev/github](http://bhat.dev/github) does not work but
[bhat.dev/github/](http://bhat.dev/github/) does.

however, [bhat.dev/gitlab](http://bhat.dev/gitlab) works without the / in the end.

can someone tell me why?

what i did was create a folder named github in my GitHub page. [repo](http://github.com/jagannathbhat/bhat.dev)

Answer (score 0):

Waited for a few hours and issue was solved on its own.